# Homemade Beet Pasta loses color when cooked

Tags: pasta, beets

I love making homemade pasta, and I've been making the beet pasta for a while (I use this recipe here http://natalieparamore.com/homemade-beet-pasta/).
When I make the pasta, it gets a beautiful dark red color, like the pictures from the recipe; however, when I cook it, it loses most of it's color, and turns into a pink pasta, instead of the dark red.
Is there a way to avoid this, or reduce the loss of color? Something I can add to the recipe, a different way to make it, or something I can do before cooking the pasta?
Thanks

Comment: Are you cooking for too long? Fresh pasta needs only a couple of minutes in the boiling water. I mean literally a couple. Most pasta I have made fresh (spaghetti sizes) is ready in less than 2 minutes in boiling water. Thicker pastas may need 3 minutes.

Comment: If I cook right after I make it, it's "less worse", since it takes less time to cook, and it looses less color. If I leave it overnight to dry off, to consume the next day, it takes a while longer to cook, and it gets the pink coloring.
For spinach pasta, the effect is not as bad, but for beet, it loses a lot of it's color

Comment: Well generally fresh pasta isn't meant to be dried overnight. Beet juice is water soluble, spinach leaf not so much.

Comment: Just checking if anyone knows a different way to make it, or maybe even a type of food coloring, that could be used. Or a technique to store it. I found that, if I froze it, and the cooked it, it loses less color.

Comment: I've only made green (spinach) pasta.  From a [related question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/what-ingredients-can-be-added-to-pasta-to-give-a-different-color), tomato paste was recommended for red color.  I don't know if it'd be more stable (and if you could mix some in w/ the beets).

Comment: Oh if you just want color, then you have choices. A lot of people include coloring just as much for shift in flavor as the actual color presented.

Comment: What choices do I have? Didn't understand what you meant by that. Tks

Answer (score 1):

You could use commercial food coloring. I wouldn't tell, and it wouldn't take much. I use this brand for baking, I'm sure it would be fine in pasta:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a natural pink cake using beets. The color always baked out. Online I found out that a more acidic batter could help. So, maybe some acid in your cooking water could help.